# AntLR - String Recognition Error

Tags: string, antlr, stringescapeutils

I have an ANTLR grammar file with the string definition as below

```
STRING
:  '"' (EscapeSequence | ~('\\'|'"') )* '"' ;
fragment EscapeSequence
  :   '\\' .
;
```

But this Lexer rule ignore the escape character at the first instance of the quotes. The

> **id\=\"**

is recognized as the start of the string whereas there is a preceding escape character. this is happening only for the first quote. All the subsequent quotes, if escaped, are recognized properly.

> /id\=**\"Testing\"** -- Should not be a string as both quotes are escaped
>   /id\=**"Testing"** -- Should be a string between the quotes, since they are not escaped

The main problem to solve is to avoid the lexer from trying to recognize a string if the character (only the last one character) preceding a quote is an escape character. If there are multiple escape characters, I need to consider just one character before the starting quote.

Comment: Can you update the question to include a detailed description of your desired string syntax, with examples of both correct and incorrect strings?

Comment: Question updated with simple example of positive and negative test case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANTLR will automatically provide the behavior you desire in almost every situation. Consider the following input:

```
/id\=\"Testing\"
```

The critical requirement involves the location and length of the token preceding the first quote character. In the following block I add spaces only for illustrating conditions that occur between characters.

```
/ i d \ = \ " T e s t i n g \ "
           ^
           |
           ----------- Make sure no token can *end* here
```

By ensuring that the first `"` character is included as part of the token which also includes the `\` character before it, you ensure that the first `"` character will never be interpreted as the start of a `STRING` token.

If the above condition is not met, your `"` character *will* be treated as the start of a `STRING` token.